# How to inject JS on a UWP webview?

Tags: javascript, windows, webview, win-universal-app, code-injection

I have a webview and I would inject some JS after the page is loaded.

I know that on Android I can use

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:function foo(str) { } foo('x');");
```

but on UWP

```
WebView.Navigate("javascript:function foo(str) { } foo('x');");
```

doesn't work because Navigate wants a URI object and not a string.

How can I do?

Comment: Look up `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` :)

Comment: @Neil Turner it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**One solution:**

1. Download your web page as a string (for example using HTTPClient).
2. Combine the string with your custom JS.
3. Call [NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx) (not Navigate) and pass in your combined page.

We have used this solution once when WP8.1 had problems dealing with touch events. We injected hammer.js to all the web pages using the above method and it worked nicely.

**Another solution:**

Use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) as Neil mentioned in his comment. There's a good overview of this solution on [MSDN Forums.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37f760ff-c476-4602-b1c0-b7a62c484d6a/xaml-page-webview-control-injecting-javascript?forum=xmlandnetfx)

Comment: download every page isn't  slow?

Comment: The browser is downloading the page either way, so in our case at least, we haven't seen any performance problems.